# Setting UIViewGroupOpacity on a View by View Basis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

Is it possible to set `UIViewGroupOpacity` (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)) for a single or set of views in an application? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

before you set the alpha of the view.